# Typescript & Gatsby: gatsby-plugin-ts + graphQL queries integration

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I'm using `gatsby-plugin-ts` to generate types for my graphql page queries.

The issue I have is that all types generated return a `T | undefined` type for all fields, so I would need to check all query subfields before using them in any component, otherwise the compiler will throw an error.

Take `gatsby-plugin-image` for example. Given a query:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query IndexPage {
    banner: file(relativePath: { eq: "banner.jpg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        gatsbyImageData(width: 1920)
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

The result `data.banner` should be passed to the `getImage` function, though if you try to do so typescript understandably throws the following error, since undefined is not assignable to `IGAtsbyImageData` expected by `getImage`
[image: typescript error]

And this is even worse when it comes to more complex queries, like the ones from the markdownremark plugin: all subfields of one query result would need to be manually checked every time. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: You should switch over to https://github.com/cometkim/gatsby-plugin-typegen, which does the same thing but much better maintained.

Comment: I expected this to work outside of the box. I have the same problem, and don't want to use `gatsby-plugin-typegen` just for this. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @DerekNguyen Gatsby now includes a built-in GraphQL Typegen feature, all you need to do is turn on a config setting. https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/graphql-typegen/

Comment: @dspacejs If you don't want to use a plugin to automatically generate your typings then you can just write them manually as in Alexey Chekmarev's answer.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be caused by a bug in the `gatsby-plugin-image` typings. Unfortunately the typings for `getImage`, `getSrc`, etc. [don't match their null-safe behaviour](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/35748). This also looks like it was only partially fixed, since the troublesome `| null` type is down one level on `{ childImageSharp: { gatsbyImageData: IGatsbyImageData } | null }` (at least in the GraphQL Typegen typings - YMMV).

The easiest workaround is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```js
const result = getImage(data.banner as ImageDataLike);
```

This tells Typescript: "Hey, I know these types don't exactly match, but *trust me*, `data.banner` will always be an `ImageDataLike`".

---

Of course, you can avoid all this if you're happy to define your typings manually, as in @Alexey's answer.

If you want to stick with auto-generated types, I'd recommend upgrading to the official [GraphQL Typegen](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/graphql-typegen/) which is built into Gatsby and kept up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

type of data.banner should be ImageDataLike

```
export interface DataBannerProps {
  banner: ImageDataLike;
  alt: string;
}
```